# smbclient: access windows share

Tags: shared-folders, smb

I dont know if this is the place to ask or if network engineering is the place but here I go.

I am trying to use smbclient to access a shared folder that I shared on a w7 machine. The w7 machine got no firewalls on, and I have shared a folder for "everyone" to see but I am unable to access it.

When I run my command `smbclient -L \\Win-5jl6jdb4fqs\c$ -U 'username' -I x.x.x.x` I get this:

```
Enter WORKGROUP\username's password: 

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
        C               Disk      
        C$              Disk      Default share
        Desktop         Disk      
        HELLO           Disk      SUP
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        Users           Disk      
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Anyone know what I have to do on my w7 machine to make this work or what my command is missing to be able to access the C drive(or desktop)?

Edit: I see that I have not provided enough commands that I have tried-->

```
smbclient -L //x.x.x.x/Desktop -U 'username' -m SMB2
smbclient -L \\WIN-5JL6JDB4FQS\Desktop -U 'username' -I x.x.x.x -m SMB2
smbclient -N -L \\x.x.x.x
smbclient -L //x.x.x.x/Desktop -U 'username' -m SMB2 -W WORKGROUP
```

I also checked my computers workgroup, it is called WORKGROUP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using smbclient for my task was unnecessary. I instead use smbmap like this:

```
smbmap -H x.x.x.x -u username-p PASSWORDTOUSER --download C$/Users/username/Desktop/somefile.txt
```

This downloads the file I wanted to download.